# Replicate every row 20 times beneath the current row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replicate every row in my Excel spreadsheet 20 times.

I tried writing a script that would give me the following result
[image]

```
Sub InsertSessions()
Dim Rng As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim rRange As Range

Set rRange = Selection

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select

Rng = InputBox("Enter number of sessions:.")
For k = 1 To Rng
Rows(rRange.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
           CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Call rRange.Copy(Range(Cells(rRange.Row - 1, rRange.Column), Cells(rRange.Row - 1, rRange.Column)))

Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Simple manual way: Fill the numbers 1 to 638 adjacent to your data. Copy the whole dataset including the new column, paste below your data 19 times, then sort on the last number column.

Comment: genius..I had to read that 5 times to get it...so basically I copy all the data 19 times below it... (copy/paste 19 times) then click 'sort' after selecting them all. ha...ha. <3 how does one upvote you?

Comment: Move the mouse to the left of my comment and you should see a little grey up arrow appear - click it. :)

Comment: If @Rory's suggestion works, you can automate the copy/pasting 19 times. Turn on the macro recorder, then do this once or twice. Then you can review the code, and try to get it to loop however many times you want. Where'd you get the code you have? It's a little odd, but works, so I'm just curious.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/21912445/… – user2769025

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this should make it relatively easy and fast

```
Sub AddCols()
    Dim howMany As Integer: howMany = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter number of rows to add", title:="Bulk Add Rows", type:=1)
    Dim prods As New Collection
    Dim lrow As Long: lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim tRange As Range
    For Each tRange In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & lrow)
        'Add pointer to cell address-this way it'll adapt while we insert rows
        If Len(tRange.Value) > 0 Then prods.Add tRange
    Next
    Set tRange = Nothing

    Dim prod As Variant
    For Each prod In prods
        ActiveSheet.Range(prod.Address).EntireRow.Resize(howMany).Insert
    Next prod
    Set prod = Nothing

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:M" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select

    For Each prod In Selection
        prod.Value = prod.Offset(-1).Value
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If a solution worked for you please mark it as an answer if it has been provided as one. If it hasn't been suggested then please be sure to post it as an answer yourself.

Comment: Done, answer marked, I couldnt mark the other answer with copying / manual way.